# Wordpress custom field - css in loop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I try to insert the value of a custom field in a background-image property ( therefore not in `img src="..."')`.

In my `category.php`; I can display the custom field linked to each post; but when I put the variable in my **style ( inline css )**, wordpress always displays the same image.

The code :

```
<?php
        // The Loop
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <div class="interview">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
             <?php $photo_interview = get_field('photo_apercu', $post->ID); ?>
             <?php echo $photo_interview; ?>
             <?php the_title(); ?>
             <style type="text/css">
                .photo_interview {
                background-image: url(<?php echo $photo_interview; ?>);
                }
             </style>
             <div class="photo_interview"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
       <?php endwhile; 
        else: ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Any idea ? My page here : http://www.overso.me/category/interview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be this:

```
<?php
    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="interview">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
         <?php $photo_interview = get_field('photo_apercu', $post->ID); ?>
         <?php echo $photo_interview; ?>
         <?php the_title(); ?>
         <!-- You don't need style tags if you only want to set the background image -->
         <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $photo_interview; ?>)"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
   <?php endwhile; 
    else: ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see you haven't set the global `$post`, so get_field do not know which is needed to display. in this case it will be better to use `the_ID()` to get the current post ID inside the while loop.

Cheers

Comment: I replace `$post->ID` by `the_ID();` and nothing change. I don't understand why `echo $photo_interview;` displays the good url; but when I put the variable in the `background-image` it doesn't work.